# Replace the second occurrence of a line

Tags: shell-script

I want to remove all the occurrences of `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` except the first one from the file below. So basically I want very first occurrence of that line to be displayed and I would like all the remaining duplicate lines to be deleted. Can some one help me get the regex cmd to do that.

```
Will use per-minute statistics
Stats from 2016-06-26   00:00:00 to 2016-06-26  23:59:00
yyyy-mm-dd      hh:mm:ss
6/26/2016       0:01:00
6/26/2016       0:03:00
yyyy-mm-dd      hh:mm:ss
6/26/2016       0:01:00
yyyy-mm-dd      hh:mm:ss
6/26/2016       0:01:00
6/26/2016       0:02:00
6/26/2016       0:03:00
```

Comment: Do you really mean "_I would like all the remaining duplicate lines to be deleted_" or do you mean "_I would like all the subsequent `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` lines to be deleted_"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sed : Replace pattern on every second occurence?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44464/sed-replace-pattern-on-every-second-occurence)

Comment: This should be closed as "unclear" imo... or, if we ignore the title, as a duplicate of [Remove lines based on pattern by keeping first n lines](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/61678)

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to remove all the duplicate yyyy-mm-dd lines then

```
% sed '/^yyyy-mm-dd/,$ { n ; /^yyyy-mm-dd/d }' srcfile
Will use per-minute statistics
Stats from 2016-06-26   00:00:00 to 2016-06-26  23:59:00
yyyy-mm-dd      hh:mm:ss
6/26/2016       0:01:00
6/26/2016       0:03:00
6/26/2016       0:01:00
6/26/2016       0:01:00
6/26/2016       0:02:00
6/26/2016       0:03:00
```

If you want to remove all duplicate lines then this is a bit hack'n'slashy and inefficient, but works and is pretty easy to understand.  (You could optimise the second sed | grep, but it's easier to read this way, IMHO).

```
% sed -n '1,/^yyyy-mm-dd/p' srcfile ; sed '1,/^yyyy-mm-dd/d' srcfile | grep -v ^yyyy-mm-dd | sort -u
Will use per-minute statistics
Stats from 2016-06-26   00:00:00 to 2016-06-26  23:59:00
yyyy-mm-dd      hh:mm:ss
6/26/2016       0:01:00
6/26/2016       0:02:00
6/26/2016       0:03:00
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e '0,/^yyyy-mm-dd\s\+hh:mm:ss$/!{/^yyyy-mm-dd\s\+hh:mm:ss$/d}'
```

The `0,/pattern/` (a GNU sed feature) range matches up to the first occurrence, so `0,/pattern/!` runs the contents of the `{...}` on the remainder of the file, removing all later matches.

Comment: Note that notations using line number 0 work with GNU sed but not necessarily with other variants.

Answer (score 2):

The right tool for this is awk. It lets you express the logic in a straightforward way: set a `seen` variable the first time the pattern is seen, and skip lines matching the pattern if it has been seen already. If a line hasn't been skipped, print it.

```
awk '/^yyyy-mm-dd[ \t]+hh:mm:ss$/ {if (seen) next; ++seen}
     1 {print}'
```

This can be abbreviated, but it gets more cryptic.

```
awk '!(/^yyyy-mm-dd[ \t]+hh:mm:ss$/ && !(seen++))'
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU `ed` supports numerical offsetting of regex addresses, so you can address a range from `/pattern/+1` to the end of the file `$`. Then you can delete any lines matching the same regex within that range as `g//d`. Finally write the modified file and quit.

```
ed file << EOF
/^yyyy-mm-dd/+1,$ g//d
wq
EOF
```

or equivalently

```
 printf '/^yyyy-mm-dd/+1,$ g//d\nwq\n' | ed file
```